# Не могу понять в чем ошибка, нужно узнать четное число или нет. По заданию должен использоваться boolean

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу понять в чем ошибка, нужно узнать четное число или нет.

Comment: Код текстом напишите.

Comment: в вашем коде не хватает его части, в этом ваша ошибка - код нужно дописать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static boolean isEven(int a)
{
  return a % 2 == 0;
}
```